# Insight into this error?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

`warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/blainerichardson/Programming/Tutorials/Udemy/React-The-Complete-Guide-Incl-Redux/react-person/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.\nExit code: 1\nCommand: node install\nArguments: \nDirectory: /Users/blainerichardson/Programming/Tutorials/Udemy/React-The-Complete-Guide-Incl-Redux/react-person/node_modules/fsevents\nOutput:\nnode-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok\nnode-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.39\nnode-pre-gyp info using node@9.3.0 | darwin | x64\nnode-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Users/blainerichardson/Programming/Tutorials/Udemy/React-The-Complete-Guide-Incl-Redux/react-person/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v59-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)\nnode-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.2/fse-v1.1.2-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz\nnode-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.2/fse-v1.1.2-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.2/fse-v1.1.2-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz \nnode-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.2 and node@9.3.0 (node-v59 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) \nnode-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.2/fse-v1.1.2-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz \nnode-pre-gyp ERR! build error \nnode-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp clean' (Error: spawn node-gyp ENOENT)\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/blainerichardson/Programming/Tutorials/Udemy/React-The-Complete-Guide-Incl-Redux/react-person/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:77:29)\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! stackat ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)\nnode-pre-gyp ERR!stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:207:12)\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:389:16)\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.3.0_1/bin/node\" \"/Users/blainerichardson/Programming/Tutorials/Udemy/React-The-Complete-Guide-Incl-Redux/react-person/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/blainerichardson/Programming/Tutorials/Udemy/React-The-Complete-Guide-Incl-Redux/react-person/node_modules/fsevents\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.3.0\nnode-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-`

Everytime I use yarn to install dependencies I receive this error. It adds them to the `package.json` file, so there is no problem getting the dependencies to work. I am just concerned this will have deeper implications later down the road when actually working on deploying a production version of a different project.